# Android File.listFiles() returns null

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to access my android files through my apk and (initially) list them on my terminal. This is the code I use:

```
File basePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)getAbsolutePath();
File directory = new File(basePath);
System.out.println("" + directory.toString());
File[] directoryContents = directory.listFiles();
```

I do succeed printing this path: `/storage/emulated/0/Download` which actually exists in my android and has some files in it.

When listing files inside that directory using:

```
for (File file : directoryContents)
    {
        if (file.isFile())
            System.out.println("" + file.getName());
        else
            continue;
    }
```

I get `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array`

I also included `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` in android's manifest.

My smartphone runs on Android 7.0 if that's of any help.

Comment: [Lower target SDK version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it), it works. targetSdkVersion 22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[listFiles](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) returns an array if the File instance from which this method is called from is a directory. Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) always(i guess) returns a directory( unless you altered the os defaults). so the only thing going wrong is probably lack of permissions;

[here is how to ask permissions properly](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Answer (score 0):

Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS replace this line instance of Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()getAbsolutePath() issue will resolved.